# Compilation with module refinement

Tags: dafny

When compiling the following code:

```
module Interface {
    function addSome(n: nat): nat
        ensures addSome(n) > n
}

module Mod {
    import A : Interface
    method m() {
        assert 6 <= A.addSome(5);
        print "Test\n";
    }
}

module Implementation refines Interface {
    function addSome(n: nat): nat
        ensures addSome(n) == n + 1
    {
        n + 1
    }
}

module Mod2 refines Mod {
  import A = Implementation
}

method Main() {
    Mod2.m();
}
```

I get the output

```
Dafny program verifier finished with 5 verified, 0 errors
Compilation error: Function _0_Interface_Compile._default.addSome has no body
```

Given that `Implementation` refines `Interface`, why does the compiler need `Interface.addSome` to have a body, particularly when `addSome` is ghost anyway so shouldn't be involved in compilation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mark both `Interface` and `Mod` as `abstract`. Among other things, this means they will not be compiled, so you won't get that error.

After those two small changes, the rest of your file compiles correctly.